# Using two sets of conditions in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the count of items in my table where it should satisfy these conditions

```
status = active
type = Pre-order
date = $date_input

OR

status = active
type = Both
date = $date_input
```

I'm trying to use this statement but I'm pretty sure it's messed up.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count_date from date_restriction
where (date='$date_input' AND status='active' AND type='Pre-order') 
OR (date='$date_input' AND status='active' AND type='Both')
```

I also tried this to no avail

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count_date from date_restriction
where date='$date_input' AND status='active' AND type='Pre-order' OR type='Both'
```

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.  I suspect that your date comparisons are off, but you initial logic should be fine -- based on what you have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.  I would write this as:

```
select count(*) as count_date
from date_restriction
where date = ? AND status = 'active' AND
      type in ('Pre-order', 'Both');
```

Note:  The `?` is for a parameter so you are not munging the query string with input values.

If I had to guess why this isn't working, I would speculate that one or both of the dates have a time component.  You might try:

```
where date(date) = date(?) . . .
```

to be sure you are matching on the date, regardless of time.

Comment: $date_input is a variable I'm using throught my file, but yeah. thanks for giving me a better option. thankssss

Answer (score 1):

Whe  you have mixed AND and OR condition you need () for the or clause

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count_date 
from date_restriction
where date='$date_input' 
AND status='active' 
AND ( type='Pre-order' OR type='Both')
```

or instear of several or condition you could use a IN clause

```
 AND  type IN ('Pre-order', 'Both')
```

anyway you should avoid the use of php var in SQL you are at risk for sqlinjection .. for avoid this you should take a look  at prepared  statement and binding param for your db driver

Comment: oooh. I didn't know that. thanks. I'll look into it. your code words fine too, but the dude above answered it first. thankssss

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(id) as count_date 
FROM date_restriction 
WHERE date='$date_input' AND status='active' AND (type='Pre-order' OR type='Both');
Here, date and status both fields are common in your case; hence, don't wrap it in parenthesis whereas, add OR condition for type field only and con-cat it with AND in WHERE clause.